# Location-search yields no results

Tags: twitter

I am trying to search by location around a point.

I looked up https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tutorials/filtering-tweets-by-location and found

```
#FlagstaffFire (point_radius:[-105.292778 40.019444 25mi] OR place:"Boulder, CO" OR (profile_locality:boulder profile_region:colorado ))
```

I entered `point_radius:[-105.292778 40.019444 25mi]` and got no results.

I tried `point_radius:[-105.292778 40.019444 800mi]` and got no results.

Does that mean

1. people stopped using gps in their tweets in that area,
2. I have the wrong command or
3. the command stopped working?

Answer (score 0):

There are very few (~1-2%) of Tweets where the user has added place or GPS data. There is a chance that your filter does indeed not match anything with location.

Comment: Which social media is more often used by users who share their location?

Comment: I have no idea.